# Thymeleaf doesn`t recognize º character

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I'm working with Spring Boot and Thymeleaf and I'm having problems with charset. I've copied a config from a website that made it better, my language is spanish and I needed utf-8 and now the view loads and recognizes ñ and á é í ó ú but I also need º for ordinal numbers. And I get this error:

**There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Could not parse as expression: "1º" (template: "form" - line 54, col 32)
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: "1º" (template: "form" - line 54, col 32)
at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.StandardExpressionParser.parseExpression(StandardExpressionParser.java:131)**

```
                            <!--LINE 54--><option th:value="1º" th:text="1º"><!--This º is not recognized and causes the error, I need thymeleaf let me render it--></option>
                                    <option th:value="2º" th:text="2º"></option>
                                    <option th:value="3º" th:text="3º"></option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

the code I've copied is: 

   

     import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
    import org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine;
    import org.thymeleaf.spring5.ISpringTemplateEngine;
    import org.thymeleaf.spring5.SpringTemplateEngine;
    import org.thymeleaf.spring5.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver;
    import org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafViewResolver;
    import org.thymeleaf.templatemode.TemplateMode;
    import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ITemplateResolver;
    
    
    
    @Configuration
    public class ViewConfigurer {
    
        @Autowired
         ApplicationContext applicationContext;
        
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine((ISpringTemplateEngine) templateEngine());
  

  resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    resolver.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    return resolver;
}

@Bean
public TemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    return engine;
}

@Bean
public ITemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    resolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");
    resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    return resolver;
}

}
```

and my html has a `<meta charset="utf-8">`, I'm using thymeleaf fragments but I don't think it's the
problem.

Thymeleaf or Spring doesn't recognize º for ordinal numers, any idea?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you edit your question, and include the related Thymeleaf template? And, ideally, indicate what on line 54.

Comment: Instead of `th:value="1º"` try this: `th:value="'1º'"`. In other words, put the string literal in single quotes. You can see a syntax summary [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#standard-expression-syntax). Also, if you are only in need of a literal, then Thymeleaf is not adding any value here. Or maybe this is just for troubleshooting?

Comment: Update: I realized, to embed this character directly into your HTML page, you should use this: `&#186;` - for example `th:text="'&#186;'"`. This is the [HTML entity](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00ba/index.htm) for that character. If you want to pass this character to your Thymeleaf template from Java, you can just use the symbol itself as part of a Java string.

Comment: I putted the string in single quotes and it worked, thanks.